Horror movie about some sort of virus
I remember watching a movie when I was younger, I believe the movie may have come out in the late 90s to 2005. I am 100% certain that the movie is based on a book, the cover of both the movie and the book had a man in a astronaut/HAZMAT type suit. Title of the movie was very short, probably 1 word, or The [Insert Noun].
Again I was much younger but from what I remember;
Movie started of with a father driving in his car into some deserted town, possibly had a daughter with him. Town was essentially completely deserted but a few people still lived there, hidden. It seemed like there was a major infection, possibly of alien origin, that made whoever was infected act crazy and murder people. There were a few scenes where the main character set up some weird traps in a random house, and again in a diner like place. 

This sounds like The Andromeda Strain.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066769/

@ChadMattox Unfortunately it's not. The little I do remember of this movie is that there was barely any people in the movie from beginning to end. I believe towards the middle/end they revealed a weird creature that may have been causing the plague.

I was finally able to find the movie/book, and because I watched it so long ago the details I provided in the original question were a bit off.
The movie was Phantoms, and novel of the same name was written by Dean Koontz.
Movie synonyms from IMDb

In the peaceful town of Snowfield, Colorado something evil has wiped
  out the community. And now, it's up to a group of people to stop it,
  or at least get out of Snowfield alive.


@AnkitSharma I think that you can only do that after 2 days.

Jason Mewes, or his character Jay, is quite the fan of this movie.
